# react-native-navigation, "method does not override" for Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Hi I'm getting the following with RNN, when running `react-native run-android`:

`MainApplication.java:22: error: MainApplication is not abstract and does not override abstract method createAdditionalReactPackages() in NavigationApplication
public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication{
^
MainApplication.java:31: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^`

My MainApplication.java (snippet): https://pastebin.com/8eFNguPn

I'm using 
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.51.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was missing

```
@Override
public boolean isDebug() {
   return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the error message says: You have no method which overrides the abstract method of NavigationApplication. You have to add:

```
@Override
public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    return getPackages();
}
```

Comment: hi, the issue was getUseDeveloperSupport and I was missing the isDebug method. Fixed now. Thanks anyway, your answer was helpful